# What are some options on using the blank cards in the The Gathering Storm Expansion?

Tags: race-for-the-galaxy

I just got the `Race For The Galaxy: The Gathering Storm` expansion and it come with 18 blank cards.  What are my options for setting up these blank cards?  I'm worried I'll drastically alter the game play if I'm not careful.  Any ideas on how I can find a way to add these cards to the game without breaking the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't got the expansion (only the original game), but I've had a few ideas:

1. Duplicates. If there are existing cards in the deck which you find
   are key and don't have a duplicate, consider making another of those
   available. I'm specifically thinking of the cards that score 3VPs on a 6-development, but there's only one copy of it.
2. Copying but changing colour. If you find there's a really
   useful Mining card, but no equivalent for Alien, you could consider
   making an Alien version of it.
3. Looking at existing cards' limits.
   e.g. If you're making a 6-development, look at what the maximum
   points it's possible to score with the existing ones, and make sure
   the ones you make don't exceed that.